# Sql error thats been asked about before - Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large

Tags: magento2, database

Magento 2

When attempting to reindex - the usual error. The limitation is 65535.
By others calculations it is number of varchar attributes * 255.

However, in my case, the sql create statement for the flat table has only 198 attributes, and many of them are integers, yet we receive this error.

I do not understand, as if the calculation is 255 * number of varchar attributes, we would not be at this limit.

Could an sql engineer or someone who understands fully this issue comment on why we could see this error with our number of attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You're running into a MySQL/InnoDB server limitation that commonly occurs with a significant number of columns in a single table.

Fortunately there are several documented workarounds for it:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15585602/change-limit-for-mysql-row-size-too-large

https://www.percona.com/blog/2011/04/07/innodb-row-size-limitation/

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6598/innodb-create-table-error-row-size-too-large

Comment: I don't think you understood my question. I understand exactly the error - however I am suggesting that the math behind the number of fields I have do not equal the row limit. 65535 divided by 255 is 257. I only have 198 attributes with many of them being integer.